# Gpodder not downloading TED Talks subtitles

Tags: gpodder

I am trying to download TED Talks with subtitles in Gpodder without success.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and gpodder 3.5.2.
I made test subscriptions in TED HD talks (http://feeds.feedburner.com/TedtalksHD/) and regular talks (http://feeds.feedburner.com/tedtalks_video).
It works well for video, but without downloading subtitles.

In tools-Preferences-Extensions, TED Talks subtitles downloader is active.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TED Talks subtitles downloader is currently broken, here what I get in terminal:

```
1399579128.331572 [gpodder.download] INFO: Download was redirected (http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2014/None/TEDMusical_2014-480p.mp4). New filename: TEDMusical_2014-480p.mp4
1399579128.336851 [ted_subtitles] INFO: subtitle url: http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/1962/lang/eng
1399579128.996226 [gpodder.gtkui.main] INFO: All tasks have finished.
1399579129.035496 [gpodder.gtkui.main] INFO: All tasks have finished.
1399579129.099886 [ted_subtitles] INFO: episode url: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TedtalksHD/~3/DKXNGZwfYwo/daffodil_hudson_is_this_the_cure_for_stage_fright
1399579130.692832 [gpodder.extensions] ERROR: Error in /usr/share/gpodder/extensions/ted_subtitles.py in on_episode_downloaded: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gpodder/extensions.py", line 83, in handler
    cb_res = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/gpodder/extensions/ted_subtitles.py", line 92, in on_episode_downloaded
    intro = episode_data.split('introDuration%22%3A')[1] \
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But it's Python and can be easily fixed!

As I see, TED description page format changed.

**To fix it:**

- **replace `'introDuration%22%3A'` with `'introDuration":'` and**
- **replace `'%2C'` with `','`**

**in `/usr/share/gpodder/extensions/ted_subtitles.py`.**

I.e. starting from line 89 this code:

```
    INTRO_DEFAULT = 15
    try:
        # intro in the data could be 15 or 15.33
        intro = episode_data.split('introDuration%22%3A')[1] \
                            .split('%2C')[0] or INTRO_DEFAULT
```

should became:

```
    INTRO_DEFAULT = 15
    try:
        # intro in the data could be 15 or 15.33
        intro = episode_data.split('introDuration":')[1] \
                            .split(',')[0] or INTRO_DEFAULT
```

After this subtitles should be downloaded in the same directory with downloaded video (under same as video with but with `.srt` extension).

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with gPodder 3.5.2.

EDIT: I made pull request to gPodder with fix: https://github.com/gpodder/gpodder/pull/121